# How to do a simple url-rewrite with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

.htaccess file located in my local computer with this path localhost/test/

How to write a redirect url like

```
localhost/test/errorsample
```

to

```
localhost/test/index.php?req_dir=$var
```

in my index.php

```
<?php
    echo ($_GET['req_dir']);
?>
```

so it should show `errorsample`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ /test/index.php?req_dir=$1 [L,QSA]
```

but this depends on other rules in the .htaccess file, so in your case it might not work without changing other rules.

Explanation of the rule: `(.*)` matches everything after `test/` and is captured into the rewriting variable $1.

If you want a 302 redirect (i. e. the server tells the browser to use a different file instead), use `[L,R,QSA]` instead. Usually a rewrite is better than a redirect, because a redirect shows the rewritten url in the address bar. If you worry about canonical pages (a SEO technique), a 302 redirect to the canonical page is better than a direct rewrite.

Comment: This causes a 500 internal server error because the regex also matches the rule's target.

Comment: You are right. This could be fixed with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`, but again: it depends on the exact configuration of the web application.